# Building a Docker Image results in error while trying to install libwww-perl i.e., perl-modules_5.14.2-6 and perl_5.14.2-6 Not found

Tags: perl, ubuntu, docker, docker-build

I need the package `libwww-perl` when my ubuntu image is created in docker.
So in my Docker file, I added the line

`RUN apt-get install -y libwww-perl`

However when I'm trying to build this Docker image

`sudo docker build -t web-service:latest .`

I end up with below error.

**Error:**

```
Step 3 : RUN apt-get install -y libwww-perl
 ---> Running in 5c6c1fdd3b66
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libclass-isa-perl libencode-locale-perl libfile-listing-perl
  libfont-afm-perl libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl
  libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl
  libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libhttp-negotiate-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl
  libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libsocket6-perl libswitch-perl
  libtimedate-perl liburi-perl libwww-robotrules-perl perl perl-modules
Suggested packages:
  libdata-dump-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl libmime-base64-perl
  libauthen-ntlm-perl perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl
  libterm-readline-perl-perl libpod-plainer-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libclass-isa-perl libencode-locale-perl libfile-listing-perl
  libfont-afm-perl libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl
  libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl
  libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libhttp-negotiate-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl
  libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libsocket6-perl libswitch-perl
  libtimedate-perl liburi-perl libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl perl
  perl-modules
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 9092 kB of archives.
After this operation, 36.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libclass-isa-perl all 0.36-3 [11.9 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libswitch-perl all 2.16-2 [19.2 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libencode-locale-perl all 1.02-2 [12.0 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libtimedate-perl all 1.2000-1 [41.6 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhttp-date-perl all 6.00-1 [10.1 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libfile-listing-perl all 6.03-1 [9690 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libfont-afm-perl all 1.20-1 [14.3 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main liburi-perl all 1.59-1 [90.3 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhtml-tagset-perl all 3.20-2 [13.5 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhtml-parser-perl amd64 3.69-1build1 [97.3 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main liblwp-mediatypes-perl all 6.01-1 [17.5 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhttp-message-perl all 6.01-1 [77.6 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhtml-form-perl all 6.00-1 [22.8 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhtml-tree-perl all 4.2-1 [205 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhtml-format-perl all 2.10-1 [40.6 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhttp-cookies-perl all 6.00-2 [23.3 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhttp-daemon-perl all 6.00-1 [16.7 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhttp-negotiate-perl all 6.00-2 [13.4 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libsocket6-perl amd64 0.23-1build2 [21.9 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libio-socket-inet6-perl all 2.69-2 [14.3 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libnet-ssleay-perl amd64 1.42-1build1 [188 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libio-socket-ssl-perl all 1.53-1 [47.5 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libnet-http-perl all 6.02-1 [23.5 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libwww-robotrules-perl all 6.01-1 [14.1 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libwww-perl all 6.03-1 [156 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main liblwp-protocol-https-perl all 6.02-1 [6746 B]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libmailtools-perl all 2.08-1 [84.0 kB]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main perl-modules all 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main perl amd64 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/perl-modules_5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/perl_5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
Fetched 1293 kB in 8s (145 kB/s)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libwww-perl' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

However, When I try to manually run the command in my local machine running ubuntu, it works fine.
`apt-get install -y libwww-perl`

Any idea what's the issue?

**Update:
My Docker File Contents -**

```
FROM dockerhub.corp.comp.com/idp/docker-jvm-8
MAINTAINER bandikishores@yahoo.com

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libwww-perl

ENV basedir /opt/comp/apps/web-service
ENV libdir ${basedir}/lib
ENV confdir ${basedir}/conf
ENV bindir ${basedir}/bin
ENV logdir /opt/comp/logs/web-service

RUN mkdir -p ${libdir} ${confdir} ${logdir}
RUN chown -R nobody:nogroup ${libdir}
RUN chown -R nobody:nogroup ${confdir}
RUN chown -R nobody:nogroup ${logdir}


ADD setup.sh ${bindir}/setup.sh
ADD service_start.sh /tmp/service_start.sh
ADD healthcheck.pl /tmp/healthcheck.pl

RUN cd /tmp && mkdir test_config && mv config.jar test_config/config.jar && cd test_config && jar -xvf config.jar && rm config.jar
RUN cd /tmp && mkdir test_env && mv env.jar test_env/env.jar && cd test_env && jar -xvf env.jar && rm env.jar

RUN chown -R nobody:nogroup ${bindir}
RUN chmod -R +x ${bindir}/setup.sh

EXPOSE 11040
```

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile? Did you begin with `apt-get update`? which distribution do you use (Ubuntu, Debian, Centos, Alpine...)?

Comment: Maybe try a `RUN apt-get update` first. I'm quite new to docker myself but I believe if you look at the output of `docker ps` you can then connect to the docker image `sudo docker exec -it <containerIdOrName> bash` and then play around with the installation procedure manually until you get it to work.

Comment: I've updated my Docker File used. Yes, I've update as well. Also, I used the same dockerFile for multiple other images and they used to work fine. I started facing this issue only with this new image that I'm creating.

Comment: I think this is related to apt setup. Can you show the contents `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` inside the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was the linux image downloaded.
After using another version of the image and adding

```
RUN apt-get update
```

line before all other RUN commands even for my existing DockerFile (which worked till now) fixed the issue.

But I'm still not sure how these existing DockerFile worked till now.